# Intel x86_64 Assembly add integer to double precision float SSE, SSE2

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64, intel

In order to achieve something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < height; i++)
{
    double relY = cY-i;
    ...

L1:  
    cmp rax, [rsi]
    jz end
    mov xmm2, rax ;<----
    ...
```

How can I move 32bit int to double precision float register ? Is it possible?

Comment: Regarding the question _How can I move 32bit int to double precision float register ? Is it possible?_ If you aren't packing more than one you could just use [CVTSI2SD](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSI2SD.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what Michael Petch wrote in his comment: the instruction is `CVTSI2SD`:

```
cvtsi2sd xmm2, rax
```

Comment: That's converting a 64-bit int (`int64_t`) to 64-bit `double`.  You said in the question you wanted 32-bit int, which would be `cvtsi2sd xmm2, eax`.  (The question also uses 64-bit operand size for integer `cmp rax, [mem]`, which is also a bug if that was supposed to be 32-bit.)  If your 32-bit integer is non-negative and zero-extended to 64-bit, then either operand-size will work for conversion to `double`, but not for `cmp rax,[mem]` depending on what's next in memory.